# Custom Stream Wrapper

Tags: 7, files, stream-wrappers

I have a file field in a content type. The files uploaded by this field should be handled by a custom php script. I think the best way to get this done is to write a custom stream wrapper. However, I am not experienced about the stream wrappers and I don't know how to implement my file upload and downloads to work with this custom script.

If I go into detail, I need to POST the uploaded file to this php script like:

```
path/to/script/?action="upload"
```

It returns a File Id. Drupal will know only about this ID. If I want to download the file, the link should look like this:

```
path/to/script/?action="download"&file_id="FILE_ID"
```

Path to the script is at the moment in the same directory as Drupal, but may not necessarily stay always there. So that I need to take this into account as well.

It may be a very simple question but I couldn't get it done.

What I've done so far is:

- Implemented [hook_stream_wrappers()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_stream_wrappers/7)
- Extended [DrupalLocalStreamWrapper](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/class/DrupalLocalStreamWrapper/7) class.

The stream wrapper I created appears already as an option in the field settings, so that I can select it.

What I don't know is exactly which methods to implement in DrupalLocalStreamWrapper class. As the documentation states I must at least implement the getDirectoryPath() and getExternalUrl() methods.

Would someone direct me how to implement those methods to get it work like I described above? Is it enough to implement only those methods, or are there more methods that I should implement?

Comment: The problem you've got is that /path/to/script/?action="upload" is presumably a PHP file; `DrupalLocalStreamWrapper` translates URIs to local paths, it has no support for invoking a local PHP script. It's more likely you'll need to write a class that implements [`DrupalStreamWrapperInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/interface/DrupalStreamWrapperInterface/7) and either connects to the script via HTTP to pass through the raw data received from the request, or implement a solution which invokes PHP CLI

Comment: Thanks Clive for pointing that I need to implement DrupalStreamWrapperInterface instead of extending DrupalLocalStreamWrapper class. I'll do some work and update my question if I still can't get it work.

Comment: No problem, you might find the `AmazonS3StreamWrapper` class in the [Amazon S3 module](https://drupal.org/project/amazons3) useful for inspiration